# Error in searching specific post_type form post_type column using WooCommerce product search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, post, woocommerce

I am using [this code](http://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/) to search products from a [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/)/[WooCommerce](https://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) website.
My requirment is URL will be like "http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product"
While `s=D34` is search string.

When user will search for a string. Data will be searched from All default fields+ product's `custom filed`. The below code work fine with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34 but when `&post_type=product` is concatenated with url then it say [image]

**Code is given below**

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
global $pagenow, $wpdb;


    if ( is_search() ) {
$where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

**This is to prevent distinct values**

```
  function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
if ( is_search() ) {
    return "DISTINCT"; //to prevent duplicates
}

return $where;

}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

So What modification is required?

`URL` http://localhost/wp/?orderby=price&post_type=product work fine

but what is wrong with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product

Comment: I'm just curious (since this has kinda happened to me); try adding a cart widget, or any of the woocommerce widgets (like categories) somewhere (temporarily) on your page where your search field is, and then try searching with your second string (with `s=d34`). I've wanted to do a detailed search for woocommerce and it only worked when I had some other woocommerce widgets present on the page with the search field. It could be a woocommerce issue...

Comment: I can suggest only here, try using the given URL, may be your issue relates to url encode of characters D34 , http://localhost/wp/?post_type=product&s=D34 , it may give insight in your problem by printing where clause as below answer suggests

Comment: @dingo_d I also think its woo-commerce issue, or may be when post_type ='product' included it starts searching in specific folder like you can see in picture "Home/Shop/", well  i will try with that what you suggested.

Comment: @Abhishek I have tried with this thing before, but it did not give required results but same error.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    // a little debugging will help you..
    //print_r ($where);
    //die();

    if ( is_search() ) {

        $where = preg_replace("/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
        $where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );
```

---

Based on your updated question.

if only you've used `print_r ($where);` to check what value does `$where` contains, you will see something like these...

with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34

```
AND (((wp1_posts.post_title LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp1_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp1_posts.post_content LIKE '%D34%'))) 
AND (wp1_posts.post_password = '') 
AND wp1_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'product') 
AND (wp1_posts.post_status = 'publish')
```

with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product

```
AND (((wp1_posts.post_title LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp1_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%D34%') OR (wp1_posts.post_content LIKE '%D34%'))) 
AND (wp1_posts.post_password = '') 
AND ( ( wp1_postmeta.meta_key = '_visibility' AND CAST(wp1_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('visible','search') ) ) 
AND wp1_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp1_posts.post_status = 'publish')
```

take note of `wp1_posts.post_type` and get a hint.. be flexible on yourself and try to debug. above are results without the `$where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product') ";` though.

Comment: I modified the question, now it is more clear please take a look now. I am voting up, will accept if you modify answer

Comment: it should work... if it doesn't then it's another problem.. which can't be seen on the current given question... try deactivating plugins... or try changing themes..

Comment: there is no active plugin but only woocommerce.

Comment: I just came to know, Real problem is URL. This code is fine. I put quries directly in code to check. it only work fine with http://localhost/wp/?s=D34 when ever &post_type=product is added problem started

Comment: debug also using other themes.. like tweentytwelve

Comment: I changed value of $where with different combinations of query. it only worked without &post_type=product thing.

Comment: I sorted out the porblem. When type  localhost/wp/?s=D34 it search in Home. but when i  localhost/wp/?s=D34&post_type=product it search in Home/Shop. That is the problem